# Text To Smiles in PHP

Tags: php

Okay, so I've recently got my hands on the script to a textCMS system. However I wish to 'develop' it more for myself as its just too basic for my liking. I wouldn't say I'm a 'starter' php coder, however I'm not very advanced.

http://ppGATE.net <-- this is the CMS I am using.

Could someone please help me in introducing that when I use the online page editor, that if I use :) or :P that it changes it to a emot.

I've looked online and not really found anything that works yet.

Any help is thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str_replace(':)', '<img src="/path/to/smileyface.gif"/>', $string);
```

Repeat for the different smilies.

I'd say you are in fact a starter if you can't figure this one out on your own. You want to *replace* text smiley faces with images of smiley faces, correct? The code pretty much spells itself out.

---

If you want to get fancy like Joseph, you can also do this:

```
$emotDict = array(
    ':)' => '<img src="path/to/image/smile.gif"/>',
    ':(' => '<img src="path/to/image/sad.gif"/>'
    // and so on...
);

$updated_text = str_replace(array_keys($emotDict), array_values($emotDict), $your_text);
```

No need for regexes here.

Comment: I can do other things. I've just never had the need to do this so I never learned in. It really depends what you count as 'starter' and 'general coder' however thank you.

Comment: I would agree that you are a starter.  If you don't know how to handle basic string manipulation tasks with PHPs built in functions, you're definitely a starter.  Nothing wrong with that - just own it and learn more :).